# Name for a function that can handle arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am writing a proof, which uses functions that can handle an arbitrary number of parameters like summing, or averaging. In other words, I'm referring to functions like:

$f(x_1, ... x_n) = \sum_i x_i$, or

$f(x_1, ... x_n) = 1/n \sum_i x_i$, or even

$f(x_1, ... x_n) = \sum_i i \cdot x_i$

Clearly, $n$ can be arbitrary and these definitions would still make sense. I'd like to call these functions a name. Is there an existing name for such functions?

As an example, I'd like to be able to say: "Let $f$ be a ______ function that acts on some (or all) of the elements of $S$" (So here $f$ would be any function that accepts any number of elements from $S$ as arguments". What's the right way to word this?

Comment: The name for the set of variables as a group is often a vector.  The function you describe is then simply a function, which takes a vector as an argument.  You might use the notation 'f:\mathbb R^n\mapsto \mathbb R' as $f:\Bbb R^n\mapsto \Bbb R$.

Comment: That makes sense, but then I'd like for the function to be able to take vectors of arbitrary size. Is that standard?

Comment: @CuriousStudent In math? Not really. In computing? Certainly. But there is usually some rather simple structure to such functions in practice, as in your examples.

Comment: Thanks. The examples I gave were for illustration, but I'd like to not assume any special structure to these functions in my proof.

Comment: In mathematics, it's much more common to describe these functions as taking a *single* argument, which is a set (or in your third example, a sequence).

Comment: @CuriousStudent It ultimately comes down to the formalism you choose to work within to define what a "*variadic function*" may be, but it is common for example to extend commutative and associative binary operators to an arbitrary number of variables e.g. $\,\max(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\,$ or $\,\gcd(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\,$.

Comment: What is your set $S$ which each $x_i$ belongs to? Moreover, is it finite?

Comment: In programming languages, such functions are called [*variadic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

Comment: You could use the term [aggregating](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2251608/275313).

Comment: I don't know about a *name* for such functions, but regarding notation see [Notation for the Set of All Finite $n$-Tuples from a Set $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556342/notation-for-the-set-of-all-finite-n-tuples-from-a-set-a). Incidentally, besides $S^{*}$ and $S^{< \omega}$ mentioned there, I've seen the notation Seq($S$) (p. 46 of 1999 3rd edition of **Introduction to Set Theory** by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hinted by Fabio Somenzi and JonathanZ, in the context of computer science you can call these kind of functions [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) or [aggregating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function).

By the way, you can easily define this kind of function in a mathematically rigorous way. The intuition is that a function $f$ would have an arbitrary arity, i.e. $f$ would accept any number of elements from a set $S$ as arguments. From a rigorous prospective, you can say the domain of $f$ is the set $S^*$ (denoted also by $S^{<\omega}$) of finite sequences of elements of $S$, i.e.

\begin{align}
S^* = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overbrace{S \times \dots \times S}^{n \text{ times } S}.
\end{align}

So, for *all* $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $s_1, \dots, s_n \in S$ iff $(s_1, \dots, s_n) \in S^*$: in other words, $S^*$ contains all and only the tuples of elements of $S$, for every (finite) length.

Strictly speaking, the function $f$ defined in this way is unary (with respect to the domain $S^*$), but it perfectly translates the idea that $f$ has an arbitrary arity (with respect to $S$). How powerful the language of mathematics is!

Answer (score -1):

The term for the number of arguments a function takes is *[arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity)* and for arbitrary (but finite) arguments is the somewhat unimaginative *n-ary*.

Comment: "$n$-ary" indicates "has a fixed arity, which is equal to $n$". The word "finitary" is more apt, I think, though that is a word I would always define the first time I used it.