# Show the set of events generated buy coin tossing is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S=\{H, T\}$ be the outcome of a coin tossing experiment. If we repeat this experiment, then the sequence of possible outcomes at each round is going to be the following:
$$
\Omega = (\{H, T\}, \{HH, HT, TH, TT\}, \{HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TTH, TTT\}, \dots)
$$
or in shorthand form:
$$
\Omega = (\{H, T\}^{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}
$$

How can I show the above set is countable?

**My try**

Clearly I can say each one has $2^n$ elements where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and one can write the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Omega &= (&\{H, T\}, &\{HH, HT, TH, TT\}, &\{HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TTH, TTT\}, &\dots)\\
&\to &2^1, &2^2, &2^3, &\dots
\end{aligned}
$$
However, this is a one-to-one mapping from the cardinality of sets to the natural numbers not from the actual sets.

Can you please help me to revise my proof?

Comment: Are you sure it is countable? The set of all infinite binary sequences is uncountable because it can be mapped injectively into $[0, 1]$

Comment: Your original set is countable but it is not the same as $\{H,T\}^{\mathbb N}$ which is the set of sequences of $H$s and $T$s.

Comment: I think you are confusing $\Omega_1 = (\{H, T\}^n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$, which is a countable sequence of countable sets of finite sequences, with $\Omega_2 = \{H, T\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, which is a single uncountable set of countable sequences.  In particular, $\Omega_2 \neq \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} \Omega_1[n]$.

Comment: Contrary to what seems to be your intention, $\{H,T\}^{\mathbb N}$ is set theory notation for the set of *infinite* sequences drawn from the set $H,T$ (not the set of finite sequences). You could instead use [the linguistics notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/556395) $\{H,T\}^*$.

Comment: @L. F.: You are right. I meant what you have mentioned. I will fix my statement.

Comment: @JKL: I was wrong about the sets and I corrected the statement.

Comment: @John Douma: I was wrong about the sets and I corrected the statement.

Comment: @Lee Mosher: I was wrong about the sets and I corrected the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map $H \to 1$ and $T \to 2$. In each of your outcomes, you have a finite sequence of $H$ and $T$. You can map that sequence into a terminating representation of a number between $0$ and $1$:

$$H \to 0.1\\HT \to 0.12\\HHTHTT \to 0.112122$$
Each such number is rational, so this maps all your outcomes one-to-one with a subset of the rational numbers, which are countable.

Comment: can you elaborate on the fact why one-to-one map to a set of countable set make it countable. I am asking this because we want to have a map to natural numbers.

Comment: Any subset of a countable set is also countable (just to be sure you know: countable does not imply "infinite" - finite sets are also countable). So the image of the map is a countable set, and when the codomain is restricted to that image, it makes the map a bijection with a countable set. And since that set is countable, it has a bijection to some subset of the natural numbers. The composition of these two bijections is the bijection you are looking for.